# What is the efficient way to track an employee's working hours?

Tags: people-management

I haven't needed to manage a business's time management system since the days of a physical time sheet, as such, I'm rather antiquated!

Our company is in catering, and we bill our clients based on the number of hours that our staff work on their site.

I wouldn't track our employee working hours if we didn't need to bill for them, but here we are.

Are there any resources to quickly get started/up to speed? What should I know?

Comment: Have the staff chipped (like dogs) and then entry & exit times can be automatically logged. **Joking**

Comment: @SolarMike "nono, you're onto something" ~ some manager, somewhere

Comment: @SolarMike I think peramanent GPS tracking with leg bracelets is better.

Comment: So which problem you are trying to solve? What does a physical timesheet lack, that you need?

Comment: In my country it is mandatory by law that employers and employees montior their time. How is it for you?

Answer (score 5):

Create an time sheet in an Excel spreadsheet and ask your staff to fill it in on a weekly basis. Or print it out so they can mark it up manually.

There will be many examples online for these, so just pick one that suits you.

You could also invest in some time- keeping software, but a spreadsheet seems the most straightforward for a small business like yours.

Comment: And when they need to enter the time, then the keyboard shortcut "command" & ";" does that which avoids formatting or typing errors.

Answer (score 1):

How are you tracking when staff arrive on a client's site and who tallies the hours? Do staff self report? How critical is this to the business?

There's a company called Timesheet Mobile that provides an app that can confirm a staff member has arrived on site and provide clocking in and out that way. That might be your best option and doesn't require for the employees to make notes about their times before writing them down.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the Answer of @Snow:

- there are several reliable and simple apps which can help your employees create consistent tables without pain (I personally like "time card for Android", it is simple and does the job).
- If you have access to a Sharepoint server with sufficient control, you could create a list where you limit the visibility of the entries to the person logging and the owner of the list. Import the list as a data source for a pivot table (that's a solution we use for a team of ~30 distributed consultants)